# Django: Exclude all rows of a table that have links in another Table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two tables in my models.py, and I want to return all results from table A that have a certain slug value AND don't appear as a foreign key in table B.

My tables as in models.py:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

What is the way in views.py to return all the rows in ModelA that have the same slug ( like ModelA.objects.filter(slug=slug) ) and that don't have any links to ModelB.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-isnull):

```
>>> ModelA.objects.filter(slug__iexact="foo", modelb__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why would I check if modela is null when I am querying ModelA itself for rows that don't appear in modelb?

Comment: Because you've called the FK attribute in `ModelB` `modela` which is confusing. With the above, you are returning all rows from the `ModelA` table that have a particular slug and don't have any reverse FK from `ModelB`

Comment: I think you mean `modelb__isnull`. It's a reverse relationship which gets the name of the model by default (when there's no `related_name` attribute).

Comment: Yep. Sorry, my mistake. I added a `related_name` and the removed it before I posted so I must have confused myself. It should be `modelb`. I updated the answer